# "correct" way to write wcf that gets data from database

Tags: database, wcf, app-config

Is there a way to write wcf that gets lots of rows from the database, without increasing (e.g.) MaxReceivedMessageSize to (e.g.) 16777216 ?

Currently, my app.config includes: 
maxBufferPoolSize="16777216" maxBufferSize="16777216" maxReceivedMessageSize="16777216"

"Just to make it work"

Comment: If you don't need all the rows at once, you could implement paging of some sort.

Comment: Thanks Tim... But I do need them :)